# Filter questions with or without accepted answer?

Tags: support

Maybe is missed something, but is a there a way to hide/show questions with an accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the search parameter `hasaccepted:no`. Here is the list of [newest questions without accepted answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3Ano).

See the [search help page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for other search parameters. To use them efficiently, find a combination that works for you best and bookmark the search page. For example: [newest questions within my favorite tags that are not closed and do not have an accepted answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3Ano%20closed%3Ano%20intags%3Amine).